# I'm having issues debugging a game I'm writing in Pycharm, how do I input a keystroke to move a character?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm trying to debug a game that I'm starting with Pycharm and Pygame.  I'm having an issue where my character is being redrawn at the wrong locations on the screen when I press up, down,left, and right.  How do I input a keystroke in the window that I've drawn and have it show up in debug window?  When I step through my code it doesn't seem to be taking a key event.

I've tried everything I can think of in debugger, including inputing a keystroke in the Console window.